# what is meaning of export in multiple-line variable

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

What is the meaning of `export` in this multiple-line variable?

In this example even i command `export foo` or not, the 
output is 'welcome'.

```
define foo  
echo welcome
endef
export foo
all:
      @$(foo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable values of the top-level `make` can be passed to the `sub-make`(sub directory makefile) through the environment by explicit request. 
These variables are defined in the sub-make as defaults.

The special variables SHELL and MAKEFLAGS are always exported (unless you unexport them).

If you want to export specific variables to a sub-make, use the export directive, like this:

`export variable`

If you want to prevent a variable from being exported, use the unexport directive, like this:

`unexport variable`

Comment: More details: any variable make takes in from its parent's environment is automatically exported to its children as well. _In addition_ to those, any variable marked `export` in the makefile is also exported.  `SHELL` actually is a special case that has slightly different behavior.